# How to add CSS file in a Magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, css, admin-panel

I am trying to add a CSS file in Magento admin section. 
Using following code in local.xml, I have added one JS file :

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                 <type>skin_js</type>
                     <name>my_folder/my_js.js</name>
                 <params/>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But I not able to attach a CSS file in admin section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to skin/adminhtml/default/default and place your file under module/custom.css
2. Go to app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout and create the file module.xml with the following code:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <layout>
>     <default>
>         <reference name="head">
>             <action method="addCss">
>                 <name>module/custom.css</name>
>             </action>
>         </reference>
>     </default>
> </layout>
> ```

3. Now connect your xml file to the module in Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml:

> ```
> <config>
> ...
> <adminhtml>
>     <layout>
>         <updates>
>             <namespace_module>
>                 <file>module.xml</file>
>             </namespace_module>
>         </updates>
>     </layout>
> </adminhtml>
> ...
> </config>
> ```

**Hope this will help you**

Answer (score 1):

Please check below reference Url.

> http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/
>   http://blog.belvg.com/use-a-local-xml-file.html

Hope this will help you.